# Retrieving the latest 10 messages from PubNub server

Tags: ios, pubnub

Per the latest PubNub 3.6.2 [documentation](https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/tree/master/iOS), I am using the the following method to retrieve the latest 10 messages sent in a channel:

```
PNDate *now = [PNDate dateWithDate:[NSDate date]];
[PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:self.currentChannel from:nil to:now limit:10 reverseHistory:YES includingTimeToken:YES withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *retrivedMessages, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *beginDate, PNDate *endDate, PNError *error) {
...}];
```

My issue is, after 10 messages have been sent in this channel, this method will only retrieve the **first** 10 messages, and not the latest 10 messages. I thought using `from:nil to:now` would always be getting the latest messages, and was wondering if there is something I missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

daspianist,

The reason you are getting the first 10 Messages is that you are have specified `reverseHistory:YES`. This has the effect of traversing message history starting with the oldest message first.

For example if my message queue is: `1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10` (Where `1` is the oldest message and `10` is the latest message).

`[PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:self.currentChannel from:nil to:now limit:3 reverseHistory:YES includingTimeToken:YES withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *retrivedMessages, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *beginDate, PNDate *endDate, PNError *error) {
...}];`

Should return: 
`[1,2,3]`

By setting `reverseHistory:NO`, the call should the most recent messages in the queue.

So based on the previous example:

`[PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:self.currentChannel from:nil to:now limit:3 reverseHistory:NO includingTimeToken:YES withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *retrivedMessages, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *beginDate, PNDate *endDate, PNError *error) {
...}];`

Should return: 
`[8,9,10]`

Comment: This is great - and yes, setting `reverseHistory` was the best way to correct it.